# In JavaScript, what is the purpose of self-calling `call`?

Tags: javascript

I'm maintaining a javascript library whose original author is not longer working at the company.

I've found the following pattern repeated across the library:

```
 var events = {}; // defined globally

 // many lines below within a function:
 if(!events.hasOwnProperty.call(events, eventKey)) return;
```

Does the use of `call` in that way offer any technical advantage over just doing:

```
if (!events.hasOwnProperty(eventKey)) return;
```

I feel like the former is less intuitive than the latter, and the latter is more expressive assuming the output is identical

Comment: It looks like he was just confused.. It reminds me of people sometimes typing `if ((a < b) == true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the same! There is no diffrerence. Any Object `{}` has the method `hasOwnProperty()` (`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`), what is a function (or function object) and any function (-object) has a method `call()` (`Function.prototype.call`) [mdn-docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

And the first argument of `Function.prototype.call()` is the »this context/object«, or context/sidecar/this/that/etc…

So, in your case: `events.hasOwnProperty.call(events, …)` is just the very same as `events.hasOwnProperty(…)`, since in the first case `events` will be `this`, because it was used as first argument to `call()`. In the latter case, `events` will also be `this`, since JS will always set the context/this automatically on each objects' method, if you do `obj.method()`.

Or in code:

```
var 
  A = { log: console.log(this) },
  B = {};

A.log() // A
A.log.call(A) // A

A.log.call(B) // B
```

Comment: That's why I was scratching my head over and over trying to see if I was missing something before updating that line to one that makes more sense.

Comment: Shorter than 99% of comments.